# session object design pattern

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to build an ajax page; it's a reporting page. By default, load today's report. On the page there's a calendar control and when the user clicks on a date, reload the gridview with the corresponding data. Is it considered good practice to do the following:

```
1) on the first page load, query the data for the page
2) put the query result in the session object and display it in a gridview
3) if the user requests new data, get new data from the query with different parameters
4) put the result of the second query in the session object and display it
5) if the user then requests the data from the first query, get it from the session object
6) do the sorting and paging with the data held in the session.
```

Note: the data of each query will contain about 300-500 rows and about 15 columns. I'd like to do all this with ajax calls. What are some suggestions and pitfalls to avoid.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Session to store temporary information that you intend to share between pages? It sounds like you're loading things into session that will be displayed onto the page that generated the data. If so, then you shouldn't put the data into session first.

Comment: It's a reporting page. By default, load today's report. On the page there's a calendar control and when the user clicks on a date, reload the gridview with the corresponding data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/):

1. Server produces report in JSON format.
2. Client has a Backbone.js Model for this report, which binds to the JSON endpoint.
3. Client renders the Report Model as a Backbone view.
4. Client reloads the report from server only when appropriate.

Reports from previously viewed days will still be around in the client as Backbone Model instances, so you don't need to reload from server unless the user forces.  I believe this is your main concern?

You're probably still in the realm of can-do-without-a-client-side-framework, but if you plan on doing more of these pages or getting any more complex, you can go to spaghetti pretty quickly without something like Backbone.js.

PS. I just noticed this is .NET related.  I know nothing about .NET so maybe there's a built-in client-side framework that can do something similar.

**EDIT (updated after reading comment):**

For server-side caching, I think a either a denormalized report table in the DB or a separate dedicated cache store (e.g. memcache) is a better practice than session object.

It depends though.  If there was say, 1 possible report per-user per-day, and you didn't have memcache set up, and you don't want to use the DB for whatever reason, then it could make sense to store it in their session object.  However, if each day's report is the same for all users, you're now caching it N times instead of 1.  It could also be hard to invalidate from an external hook and the user loses their cache when they logout.

So I would probably just have a typical get-or-set pattern to try and load report from cache first, and fallback to DB.  Then invalidate/update the cached report only when the user forces, or if data used to create the report has changed.  AJAX call requests the report by date or however a report is identified.

Comment: this looks pretty cool! thanks. I'm going to look into it for a different purpose. However, for the current page, I'm looking at server side caching.

Comment: cool! no problem. i expanded the answer with some thoughts on server-side caching

Answer (score 2):

Since you are hoping to use the data in Javascript Ajax scenerios it would make the most sense to create a [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) to query and return the needed data result sets on demand.

Using the session object is not a solution because it cannot be accessed asynchronously. As a result, your page would not be able to query this data to feed back to your Javascript objects (unless you created an HTTP Handler to send it back, but that would be pointless when you could just query the data in the HTTP Handler directly).

Comment: What part is confusing so I can clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting about windows. A client isn't a window, a client is a browser it can contain many windows/tabs. You need to make sure you are rendering/feeding the correct window. Usually i handle this by submit hidden values.

Problem is separating resuming a session / Starting a new window.

Comment: What does the client user agent have to do with the question? The client user agent doesn't make it a good or bad idea to use session to store database results for display on the same page.

Comment: @Frazell Thomas User agent? What? Where what did I write, Who where, What? When How?

Comment: @Stefan The Browser is the User Agent (official name for Browser). I was saying it doesn't matter what the client browser is doing (multiple tabs, etc.) in the context of his question.

Comment: @Frazell Thomas It does matter if you open multiple tabs/windows to the same site/page. By just referring to a session you dont refer to a specific window but to a browser instance.

Comment: I should have added the context: it's a reporting page. By default, load today's report. On the page there's a calendar control and when the user clicks on a date, reload the gridview with the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother holding more than one copy of the query in the Session.  The primary reason you'd want to hold it in Session is to improve the sorting/paging speed, presumably.  Users expect those to be relatively fast, but choosing new dates can be slower.  Plus, what's the likelihood that they'll really reload the first query?

The other answers raise good pitfalls with storing in Session in general.